# On proving that if $g_n \to g$ pointwise and $(g_n)$ is uniformly bounded, then $g_n(U) \to g(U)$ strongly.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functional-calculus

I'm trying to prove that if $U : H \to H$ is an bounded operator in a Hilbert space for which functional calculus is well defined (say, $U$ self adjoint and compact) and $g_n : \sigma(A) \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, uniformly bounded and pointwise covergent to certain $g : \sigma(A) \to \mathbb{R}$, then

$$
g_n(U) \to g(U)
$$

in the sense of **strong** convergence.

So far, I've done the following: for each $h \in H$ we have the spectral measure $d\mu_h$ for which satisfies 
$$Q_h(f) = \langle f(U)h,h \rangle = \int_{\sigma(U)}f_nd\mu_h$$
for any continuous $f : \sigma(U) \to \mathbb{R}$. By dominated convergence we get $Q_h(g_n) \to Q_h(g)$ for all $h \in H$ and via a polarization identity the former gives
$$\langle g_n(U)u,v\rangle \to \langle g(U)u,v\rangle$$
for all $u,v \in H$.

I haven't been able to conclude anything from here. Any hints you could provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am I correct in believing that $(g_n(U))_n$ is a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson $(g_n(U))_n$ is a sequence of bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is that for every $u \in H$, $g_n(U)u \rightharpoonup g(U)u$ in $H$. Recall that $x_n \to x$ in $H$ if and only if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$. This means that it is now enough to show that $\|g_n(U)u\| \to \|g(U)u\|$.

For this, notice that $$\|g_n(U)u\|^2 = \langle g_n(U)u , g_n(U)u \rangle = \langle g_n(U)^* g_n(U) u, u \rangle = \langle \overline{g_n}(U) g_n(U)u, u \rangle$$
where $\overline{g_n}$ is the complex conjugate of $g$. To conclude, notice that $\overline{g_n}(U) g_n(U) = (\overline{g_n}g)(U)$ and $\overline{g_n}g$ is a sequence of continuous functions which is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise to $\overline{g}g$. Hence $(\overline{g_n}g)(U)u \rightharpoonup (\overline{g}g)(U)u$ so that
$$\|g_n(U)u\|^2 = \langle \overline{g_n}(U) g_n(U)u, u \rangle \to \langle (\overline{g}g)(U)u, u \rangle = \langle g(U)^*g(U)u, u \rangle = \|g(U)u\|^2$$
which gives the desired convergence of norms.

Comment: I really appreciate that you have taken the time once again to answer my rather naïve questions. I had thought of using weak convergence but didn't see that I could use self adjointness! Thanks, Rhys.

Comment: In my opinion both of your questions have been well-formulated and show genuine effort on your part to solve them so are well-deserving of answers. I'm glad I could help. I want to note though that self-adjointness is more than either of us use in all of this. The whole thing would work in exactly the same way if we assume only that $U$ is a bounded normal operator since there is a functional calculus with the right properties in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. I suspected this holds in full generality (as claimed by the material I'm reading), but I have to adapt everything to the case of compact self adjoint operators. A follow up question: do you know of any interesting applications of functional calculus that are fairly direct to prove? So far I've found the existence of $n$ -th roots and I think I've proved Neumann's ergodic theorem when $U$ is compact self adjoint and  $\sigma(U) \subset [-1,1]$ (does that make sense? I basically tried to mimic the proof for unitary operators in which we integrate on the circle).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a particular expert on this topic so I can't give you any good recommendations for other areas to look into. Maybe you could ask another question here and someone with more expertise will answer. In fact, I've only seen a proof of Von Neumann's ergodic theorem via a slick computation using a cleverly chosen orthogonal decomposition. Do you have a reference for the proof you mention? I'd also be interested in a reference to the material you're reading to try to work out what "full generality" means in this context

Comment: I haven't used "full generality" very precisely. I'm reading bits of Rudin, Reed & Simon's book I was recommended in my last question, Brezis' book and some other notes in spanish (plus the ones of my last question). I think the proof you reference is due to Riesz, the one due to Von Neumann uses spectral measures (it can be found in Rudin's book).

Comment: (cont.) I've think I've managed to adapt it to my more restrictive situation. Concretely, if $U$ is self adjoint and compact and $\sigma(U) \subset [-1,1]$, then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_iU^i \to \pi_{E_1}$ SOT, where $\pi_{E_1}$ is the projection to the fixed points of $U$. Using the proposition of this question, this translates into proving that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x^i$ are uniformly bounded in $[-1,1]$ and converge pointwise to the indicator function of $\{1\}$ (as $\pi_{E_1} = \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(U)$).